# Summary of Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table called `questions` containing following data. The data is collected by answers from people. Each question contains max 20 options.

```
form      q1      q2        q3      q4        q5     q6  
1         16       1         2       5        11      9
2         9        6         16      5        2       8
3         8        3         2       5        11      9
4         16       1         2       5        11      7
5         16       6         4       5        11      4
6         15       1         2       5        11      3
7         16       1         2       5        11      4
8         15       1         16      5        11      6
.
.
```

One person can answer only once. There are more than 100000 peoples who answered. Every one have to answered these six questions.
The result is announced every one hour so i have to find out the summary after every answer. There is another table where i kept correct answers of all six questions

```
question      Answer
 1             16
 2              1
 3              2
 4              5
 5              11 
 6              9
```

Now I want my output be like as follows after first result:

```
1 / 6 (1 correct answer out of 6 )= 4
```

after second result:

```
2 / 6 (1 correct answer out of 6 )= 3
1 / 6 (1 correct answer out of 6 )= 3
```

after third result:

```
3 / 6 (1 correct answer out of 6 )= 3
2 / 6 (1 correct answer out of 6 )= 1 
1 / 6 (1 correct answer out of 6 )= 3 
.
.so on till sixth result
.
```

after sixth result:

```
6/ 6 (1 correct answer out of 6 )= 1
5 / 6 (1 correct answer out of 6 )= 2 
4 / 6 (1 correct answer out of 6 )= some value
3 / 6 (1 correct answer out of 6 )= some value
2 / 6 (1 correct answer out of 6 )= some value 
1 / 6 (1 correct answer out of 6 )= some value
```

I want the result in descending order. if there is no matching then it will show 0.

Comment: I am sorry but this is unintelligible (to my poor brain at least).  Do you want output per candidate? Also please check your examples.  For instance "Some Value". This is less than helpful.  Also please explain the logic again e.g. after third result 3/6 = 3 2/6 = 1 1/6 = 3.

Comment: `after first result:

1 / 6 (1 correct answer out of 6 )= 4` Isn't the first result gets all correct ? why it is `1 correct` ? also please explain how do you get the `4` ?

Comment: @Jonathan Willcock i want output when ever result of question be announced and after that i have to some up all peoples who have answered correctly . 
1/6 mean at least one answer is correct out of six
2/6 mean at least two answer are correct out of six
3/6 mean at least three answer are correct out of six
4/6 mean at least four answer are correct out of six
5/6 mean at least five answer are correct out of six
6/6 mean at least six answer is correct out of six

Comment: if first answer will announced i have to show only people have correct first answer and will display 1/6. If second answer is announced then i have to show 1/6 and 2/6 in descending order and so on till 6th answer

Comment: @ Squirrel 
in table two the correct answer for first question is "16". and from first table it is visible that 3 people answered correctly for q1 so after first result the 1/6 is 3.

Comment: @mks I think I finally understood what you  want ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use a query like this:

```
;with unpivoted as (
    select form, 1 question, q1 answer from questions q
    union all
    select form, 2 question, q2 answer from questions q
    union all
    select form, 3 question, q3 answer from questions q
    union all
    select form, 4 question, q4 answer from questions q
    union all
    select form, 5 question, q5 answer from questions q
    union all
    select form, 6 question, q6 answer from questions q
), results as (
    select u.form, count(ca.Answer) corrects
    from unpivoted u
    left join correctAnswers ca
      on u.question = ca.question and u.answer = ca.Answer
    group by u.form
)
select cast(coalesce(u.question, r.corrects) as varchar(7)) + ' / 6' correctsPer6, count(distinct r.form) countOfForms
from unpivoted u
full outer join results r on u.question = r.corrects
group by u.question, r.corrects
order by u.question desc;
```

[**`[SQL Fiddle Demo]`**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/36319d/4)

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. Your answer is approximately correct but need two things. One it is not showing if count is 0 . for example if 6/6 is 0 then it will not show. by changing
 INSERT INTO questions
    ([form], [q1], [q2], [q3], [q4], [q5], [q6])
VALUES
    (1, 6, 1, 2, 5, 11, 9),
second is there any possibility to make it dynamic that it will show show results based on answered entered in table ..

Comment: Well, I update the answer to support that situation ;).

Answer (score 0):

```
I i do understand the question correctly, think this is what you wanted

--  Sample Table
declare @question table
(
    form    int,
    q1  int,
    q2  int,
    q3  int,
    q4  int,
    q5  int,
    q6  int
)
--  Sample Data 
insert into @question
select  1,         16,       1,          2,       5,        11,      9  UNION all
select  2,          9,       6,         16,       5,         2,      8  UNION all
select  3,          8,       3,          2,       5,        11,      9  UNION all
select  4,         16,       1,          2,       5,        11,      7  UNION all
select  5,         16,       6,          4,       5,        11,      4  UNION all
select  6,         15,       1,          2,       5,        11,      3  UNION all
select  7,         16,       1,          2,       5,        11,      4  UNION all
select  8,         15,       1,         16,       5,        11,      6

declare @answer table
(
    q   int,
    ans int
)
insert into @answer
select  1, 16   union all
select  2,  1   union all
select  3,  2   union all
select  4,  5   union all
select  5, 11   union all
select  6,  9

-- the query
; with q as
(
    -- Pivot the Question table to form, q, ans
    select  form, q, ans
    from    (
            select  form, [1] = q1, [2] = q2, [3] = q3, [4] = q4, [5] = q5, [6] = q6
            from    @question
        ) q
        unpivot
        (
            ans for
            q in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6])
        ) up
)
select  s.q,
    c.correct
from    @answer s
    cross apply
    (
        select  correct = count(*)
        from
        (
            select  q.form, correct = sum(case when a.ans = q.ans then 1 else 0 end)
            from    @answer a
                inner join q    on  a.q = q.q
            where   a.q <= s.q
            group by q.form
            having sum(case when a.ans = q.ans then 1 else 0 end) = s.q
        ) c
    ) c
```